# Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window

Tags: window, frames, emacsclient

I have a daemonized emacs, and I'm able to close any emacs frame, even the last one, using the window manager or old good `C-x C-c`, just to be able to retrieve all my buffers when i ask the daemon for a new frame.

Instead if I try to close the last displayed frame using `C-x 0` I'm told

> `Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window`

I understand that a window is not a frame, I know that the command bound to `C-x 0` is `delete-window`, nevertheless I would like to have the window/frame closed rather than the error message.

Binding `C-x 0` to `delete-frame` is not what I want, I want to kill windows with `C-x 0` but the last one, in which case only I want to have Emacs close the frame.

Comment: do you understand what this error even means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check to see what command a keybinding runs with `C-h k
KEYBINDING` (where `C-h k` runs `describe-key`).  If you do that
with `C-x 0`, you get the following docstring:

> `C-x 0` runs the command delete-window (found in global-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘window.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-x 0`.
>
> `(delete-window &optional WINDOW)`
>
> Delete WINDOW.
>   WINDOW must be a valid window and defaults to the selected one.
>   Return nil.
>
> If the variable `ignore-window-parameters` is non-nil or the
>   `delete-window` parameter of WINDOW equals `t`, do not process any
>   parameters of WINDOW.  Otherwise, if the `delete-window`
>   parameter of WINDOW specifies a function, call that function with
>   WINDOW as its sole argument and return the value returned by that
>   function.
>
> Otherwise, if WINDOW is part of an atomic window, call
>   `delete-window` with the root of the atomic window as its
>   argument.  **Signal an error if WINDOW is either the only window on
>   its frame, the last non-side window, or part of an atomic window
>   that is its frame’s root window.**

`delete-window` is for deleting *windows* and NOT *frames*.  The
docstring lets you know why it is signaling the errors you're seeing.

If you want to delete a frame, you need to use the command
`delete-frame`, which, by default, is bound to `C-x 5 0`.

If you *really* want one command to do it all, below is a simple
option (*lightly* tested) that deletes a window and, if it's the
last one, deletes the frame it's in:

```
(defun delete-window-or-frame (&optional window frame force)
  (interactive)
  (if (= 1 (length (window-list frame)))
      (delete-frame frame force)
    (delete-window window)))
```

Comment: great now I have a new error `Attempt to delete the sole visible or iconified frame`

Comment: Great function, thank you. It should be included in default Emacs.